# Is it possible to execute a CSX during a VS2017 pre-build event?

Tags: visual-studio-2017, csx

I have several complex things to accomplish before a build can begin. Writing this in batch would be a nightmare. Writing these in CS would be lovely. I think CSX would be my most reasonable approach. But, is it possible? How do I invoke it?

PS: should you happen to have a better/simpler approach, I would welcome it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How I managed to do so:

1. Add `BuildScript.csx` file to your project, containing the script you wish to run at pre-build (VS2017 would interpret .csx files as C# (intelisense etc.))
2. Add the following to the pre-build commands, to call the C# script compiler on your script:

   `"C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\csi.exe" "$(ProjectDir)BuildScript.csx"`

You can improve this and future usage of csi.exe by adding `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\` to `Path` environment variable, so the command would be:

```
csi "$(ProjectDir)BuildScript.csx"
```

---

P.S:
Could you please specify what exactly are you trying to do? There might be more simple solution.